# Convert EitherT[Future, A, Future[B]] to EitherT[Future, A, B]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am trying to change an `EitherT[Future, A, B]` to `EitherT[Future, C, D]` and for this, I am using `bimap` to map left and right parts appropriately.
While I am transforming the right part of this `EitherT`,  I am making a service call which returns me a `Future[D]`… I am having trouble converting this `Future[D]` to `D` in my `bimap`. Not sure how to proceed now. Any help here would be appreciated.

Psuedo code:

```
val myResult: EitherT[Future, C, D] = EitherT[Future, A, B](myService.doStuff())
    .bimap({ err => /*deal with errors and give me C*/ }
      ,{ success => someService.doSomething(success) // This is returing a Future[D]. But I want a D 
       })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.flatMap` aka `for`-comprehension

```
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.instances.future._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val myResult: EitherT[Future, C, D] = for {
  d <- EitherT.right(someService.doSomething())
  res <- EitherT[Future, A, B](myService.doStuff())
    .bimap({ err => ??? : C //deal with errors and give me C
    }, { success => {
      d
    }
    })
} yield res
```

---

Try `.biSemiflatMap`

```
val myResult: EitherT[Future, C, D] =
  EitherT[Future, A, B](myService.doStuff())
    .biSemiflatMap({ err => Future.successful(??? : C)
    }, { success => {
      someService.doSomething(success)
    }
    })
```

Comment: Oh shoot! `someService.doSomething()` is supposed to be `someService.doSomething(success)` actually. :( Will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Nice! I was able to use your first suggestion to figure it out!... Thanks a lot. For some  reason, I was not able to find `biSemiflatMap` could be the fact that I am on an old version of cats library.